# Create a new image from a container’s changes in Google Cloud Container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an Image which i should add a dependency to it. Therefore I have tried to change the image when is running on the container and create new Image.
I have follow [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-commit-changes-to-a-docker-image/) with the following commands after :

```
kubectl run my-app --image=gcr.io/my-project-id/my-app-image:v1 --port 8080
kubectl get pods
kubectl exec -it my-app-container-id -- /bin/bash
```

then in the shell of container, i have installed the dependency using "pip install NAME_OF_Dependncy".
Then I have exited from the shell of container and as it have been explained in the article, i should commit the change using this command :

```
sudo docker commit CONTAINER_ID nginx-template
```

But I can not find the corresponding command for Google Kubernetes Engine with **kubectl**

How should i do the commit in google container engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with K8s Version 1.8. There is no way to do Hot Fix changes directly to the images.For example, Committing new image from running container. If you still change or add something by using `exec`  it will stay until the container is running. It's **not best practice** in K8s eco-system.

**The recommended** way is to use **Dockerfile** and customise the images according to the necessity and requirements.After that, you can push that images to the registry(public/ private ) and deploy it with K8s manifest file.

**Solution to your issue**

- Create a Dockerfile for your images.
- Build the image by using Dockerfile.
- Push the image to the registry.
- write the deployment manifest file as well service manifest file.
- apply the manifest file to the k8s cluster.

Now If you want to change/modify something, you just need to change/modify the Dockerfile and follow the remaining steps.

As you know that containers are a short living creature which does not have persist changed behaviour ( modified configuration, changing file system).Therefore, It's better to give new behaviour or modification at the Dockerfile.

**Kubernetes Mantra**
Kubernetes is Cloud Native product which means it does not matter whether you are using Google Cloud, AWS or Azure. It needs to have consistent behaviour on each cloud provider.

Comment: I am new with docker, can you tell me by using your solution with Dockerfile, is it possible to create a new image having an existing Image? i should just add a dependency so what is the most straight forward way to do it ?

Comment: Each Image is created using Dockerfile due to transparency, customization, version control etc. If you have an existing Dockerfile, You just need to add your dependency. For example, 'RUN pip install NAME_OF_Dependncy' would be another line in the Dockerfile.  I would suggest you to further read about How to write Dockerfile and functionality of each line in Dockerfile. it would give you a comprehensive idea. If you more doubt let me know. I will try my best to give you direction.

Comment: I don't have an existing DockerFile, i have just pull it from dockerhub. I gonna study how to write a DockeFile, but just can you kindly tell me if it is possible to follow your solution to create a new image using an existing image without having its DockerFile?

Comment: If I do not have Dockerfile, then I would build a new image by using commit command from the running container.  Afterwards, I will push it to registry then I would use this new image. For example , "kubectl run my-app --image=gcr.io/my-project-id/NEW-IMAGE --port 8080"  
As you can see this process is error-prone as well as quite manual but it will work for your situation if you do not have Dockerfile.

Comment: As I have explained in the Question, the MAIN problem is that i don't know how  to use Commit Command, as I didn't find corresponding command for Google Kubernetes Engine with kubectl . From the running container i can not run any docker command, and from Google Cloud shell, i can not use docker commit, because i should use Kubectl

Comment: There is no other way to do it As k8s does not support kubectl commit. Otherwise, we can wait for other people's answer. I have shared my knowledge with you.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/deploying-flogo-apps-to-kubernetes-43a74742e323

It might give you some reasonable thoughts of workflow in docker and kubernetes.

Comment: I just asked a related question but about Google's sample images on GCR.  Any chance you know whether the Dockerfiles for Google's sample images are publicly available?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435401/are-dockerfiles-available-for-googles-sample-images-on-google-container-registr